Is there a way to create a bas relief in blender?
I have been exploring creating a bas relief in Blender with z depth, but I don't like the results, I want something like Relief Maker. 

Since we have no idea what "Relief Maker" actually does or what its result looks like we can't answer that! Add an image of the result it produces and the source image that it's derived from and someone here might be able to offer a suggestion.

I would try to A-increase the image contrast; B-create a smooth modifier; and C what happens...

https://blendermarket.com/products/bildeform
Look at this, It's an addon that I just found for Blender, it seems to give very good results.

Displacement works by displacing each vertex by an amount corresponding to the texture's pixel value, the displacement's midlevel property serving as an "origin" from which interpret the texture's values as displacement amounts, and then the displacement's strength property serves as an amplitude multiplication.
Those properties need to be adapted to your texture, and to your end goal. When done right, and with a correct texture, it should look ok:

The fact that your resulting mesh have a huge gap and then minimal height difference lets me think that your midlevel isn't correct. By default, it would be at 0.5, you set it to 0. If your displacement texture was made with a black background, it would work, so I guess it isn't.
I can't tell which value you should use without the texture, but one way to find it exactly is to open your texture in the image editor, and hold down  RMB on the color that is your base. You should see its value in the image editor footer:

Put that as your midlevel, then adjust the strength to how big the effect you want. But bear in mind that it really is the texture that dictates what strength the displacement can take. If the texture's values aren't plenty enough (typically using 8bits images instead of 16 or 32), you will easily get steps of height or steep pikes everywhere. Or if the values are incorrectly spread on the value spectrum, you will not get the deformation you want.
That being said, Hence, make sure your texture is as high of a bit depth you can. And if the height difference doesn't go as you like in different areas, you can always edit the texture itself. Or, rely on shader-based displacement, where you can do some slight changes on the texture with nodes before feeding it to your material's displacement:

Don't forget to enable displacement in the material option, and set the texture's color space to Non-Color.
